# preg_match and weird encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I need to parse a file and find some predefined expressions, with for example `preg_match` ; here is the problem : there seems to be an encoding problem, because I am unable to find anything (with two local vars, it works great !). 
I don't know the real encoding of my file, so I tryed using `mb_detect_encoding` that returns me 'ASCII'.
I am currently trying to convert each of my string (pattern and expr) into the same format, but it still doesn't work... Here is my code, do you have an idea ?

Thanks

```
foreach( $expr as $exp ) {
    $patternForRegex = mb_convert_encoding( $pattern, mb_detect_encoding( $exp ) );

    if( preg_match( $patternForRegex, $exp ) ) {
        echo "find!" ;

        $matchedExprs[ $key ][] = $exp;
    }       
}
```

Comment: We cannot really help if you don't post your data.

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` is all but reliable. It has several problems: only works on very few encodings and even then it is pretty dump. For example it only checks the first 500 chars...

Comment: My datas are confidentials, so I sadly can't show you the file ; but it comes from Google Adwords csv, and seems to be UTF-16 encoded..

Comment: Not sure right now, I only have experience with utf-8, not utf-16... 1.) check if/how the string functions are overloaded inside your php installation/configuration. You need the mb_string overloaded versions, otherwise you cannot apply a regex to a utf encoded string. 2.) create your script (the pattern) directly in utf16 using an editor where you can easily switch the encoding. 3.) Tripple check (unsing a hexeditor is the only way) that your pattern _really_ is encoded in utf-16. 4.) Compare pattern and subject in a hexeditor if there still is no match...